# Adobe Acrobat: Is there a way to get rid of the arrow of a dropdown after selecting an option that does not lock selecting a different option?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have found numerous articles with the same one person replying saying that this is impossible to do in Adobe Acorobat. I was wondering if there was some code I could right into the pdf that would allow the arrow of the dropdown to disappear without locking it and making it unable to be edited.

I found code that said it would work but it was only for being able to print it without any arrows. One the code resulted in errors and two printing it in my case locks the form anyways.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is this Acrobat Pro Folder script, also I do not want to lock it against reuse because the people are filling out these forms on ipads so it is really easy to make a mistake

Comment: Instead of using a dropdown, you can use a regular text field that displays a popup menu when clicked, allowing selection of a value from a list. No arrow is shown. If sounds like an acceptable solution, I can add the code as an answer along with a functioning example.

Comment: @joelgeraci That sounds like a great solution, what would the code be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the effect you want, don't use a dropdown field. Instead, use a text field with a popup menu. Create a text field then add the following JavaScript to the OnFocus event in the Actions tab. See image for the Acrobat UI steps. The parameters in the popUpMenu method will build the menu to select from. Once selected, the value will show in the field. A working example is located [here](https://practicalpdf.com/techniques/pdf/PopupMenu.pdf).

```
var selection = app.popUpMenu("Dogs", "Cats", "Birds");
event.target.value = selection;
```

[image]